# $Http Qual e que devo Usar?

Tags: angularjs, http

O `$http` tem dois exemplos. Gostaria que me ajudassem pois não sei qual é o mais útil

Existe o :

```
var chamada = function () {
    return $http.get('https:url/exemplo.json')
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
         });
    }
```

e o :

```
 var outraChamada = function () {
     return $http.get('https:url/outroExemplo.json')
         .success(function (data) {
             return data;
         }).error(function (status) {
             return status;
         })
     }
```

Por qual devo Optar? Existe alguma forma de me devolver a data se a mesma for alterada no Web Service(sem ser preciso chamar a função)?

Comment: "Existe alguma forma de me devolver a data se a mesma for alterada no Web Service(sem ser preciso chamar a função)?" Tu tá dizendo algo mágico, em que ele iria se atualizar sozinho sem chamar o web service? Se for isso, não, não tem nenhuma magia pra isso ainda(não pronta).

Comment: `success` e `error` são callbacks marcados como *deprecated*, use *then*. Fonte: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize o `then` pois como o @lbotinelly disse o `success` e `error` estão *deprecated*.

```
$http.get('https:url/exemplo.json')
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

> Existe alguma forma de me devolver a data se a mesma for alterada no
>   Web Service(sem ser preciso chamar a função)?

R: Não, não tem como sua pagina saber "sozinha" se algo foi alterado no back-end. Existem algumas alternativas, uma delas é criar uma função que faça uma verificação a cada x minutos e verifique se algo mudou, nesse caso você pode usar o [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout).

Comment: Muito obrigado Muito Útil

Answer (score 1):

***$http.get()*** retorna um objeto *Promise*, que nos permite encadear funções como se elas fossem síncronas.

A função encadeada ***then()*** aceita dois argumentos: um *handler* de sucesso e um *handler* de erro.

O correto é utilizar esse formato disponível na [documentação](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) (o *success* e *error* estão *deprecated*):

```
$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Exemplo:

```
var chamada = function () {
    return $http.get('https:url/exemplo.json').then(this.sucesso, this.erro);
}

this.sucesso = function(response) {
    return response.data;
}

this.erro = function(error) {
    console.log('Não foi possível obter os dados: ' + error.data);
}
```